# The piece at the top of the bottom sheet Flutter

Tags: flutter

What is the correct name for this part marked in red?

[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe it comes by default on IOS, not sure but you can crete custom comtainer/divider widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Material 3 spec for bottom sheets](https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-sheets/specs) refers to this as the **Drag handle**.